# SharePoint dashboard and KPI

Tags: excel-services

Is there any way to create a dashboard, and use KPI from a shared doc lib that contain excel sheets ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend migrating your use of Excel Spreadsheets to store the KPIs onto using Custom Lists within the SharePoint platform. There, you will be able to easily produce KPI reporting based on this SharePoint List.

This method is dependent on the requirements of both your reporting and your acquisition of the data used for the KPI, and also the version of SharePoint which you are using, all of which you have not stated, so a realistic and fulfilling solution cannot yet be recommended.

Comment: how to link the sharepoint list, with a excel sheet column ?

Comment: Once you have created a SharePoint list from a template or with custom columns, you can link to Excel by using the option in the "Actions" menu in the toolbar of the List.